# How to add an assembly reference to a VS 2015 vNext .NET 4.x targeted Project

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

Visual Studio 2015 supports multiple build targets in a vNext project so you can build for vNext CLR, vNext Core **and** any other .NET build targets.

I understand that vNext project require that dependencies have to be referenced via NuGet packages, but how can I add assembly references to the non-vNext projects that might require GAC or other external dependencies?

My References structure looks like this:

- .NET Framework 4.5   <--- how do I get an GAC/assembly reference into this?
- ASP.NET 5.0
- ASP.NET Core 5.0

Use case: I'm building a library that can work both on standard CLR and the new vNext CLRs, but the standard version requires access to System.Configuration. How do I get the reference of System.Configuration into the classic .NET 4.5 target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you can add framework libraries like "System.Runtime.Serialization" to the "frameworkAssemblies". (But I'm not sure this will also work with GAC.)

See example project.json file:

```
"net45": {
        "frameworkAssemblies": {
            "System.Runtime.Serialization": "4.0.0.0"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "System.Reflection": "4.0.10-beta-22416",
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yup that works for GAC refs. Or files you explicitly deploy in the bin folder.